# Pyspark RDD raw csv file with some rows and some columns, columns in different rows number is not same. How do i remove all the first column read in

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

i am new to pyspark and python.

Pyspark RDD i have raw csv file with some rows and some columns, columns in different rows number is not same. How do i remove the first column in all rows and store in RDD. menaing 5988 5989 ... etc... so on

Thanks

[picture](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GZkcNIqXfWNTZUTtQ9qVIZHEMcwCQdAv?usp=sharing)

[sample of csv[image: ][1]]

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the record after reading it and before you split the data into columns. One way to do that would be as below.The reason for the separate function is to keep the map simple in usage and also allows you to ignore a list of lines

```
def rdd_ignore_lines_filter(x, ignore_lines_starting_with):
    """
    Method to be used in the RDD map function to filter any records that startswith the values specified in the
    list
    :param ignore_lines_starting_with: A list of strings to be used in the filter logic
    :return: Spark RDD
    """
    valid = True
    for ignore_line in ignore_lines_starting_with:
        if x.startswith(ignore_line):
            valid = False
            break
    return valid

rdd = sc.textFile(source_location)
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: rdd_ignore_lines_filter(x,filter_list))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(delimter))
```

Tested with a file with data as below

```
something,something,something
1,1,1
2,2,2
```

Results after running on the pyspark shell

```
>>> rdd = sc.textFile('file:///home/hadoop/sample.txt')
>>> rdd.collect()
['something,something,something', '1,1,1', '2,2,2']
>>> rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: rdd_ignore_lines_filter(x,['something']))
>>> rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(','))
>>> rdd.collect()
[['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2']]
```

Comment: Filter method doesn't work. Not sure if can filter before you split csv file. Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

Comment: I’m not sure why this doesn’t work for you. This works for me. When I read the text file , each record comes as a a whole without splitting on commas or your delimiter.